# how to observe embedded youtube video

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8, youtube-iframe-api

I want to embed a youtube video on my own website and I want this youtube video not to be skipped in any way, but not to adjust its speed and to track the time it watches, but I could not find any source.

I tried to use the youtube iframe api, but I can't follow the stats without stopping or starting the youtube video there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should first download the video, and then put it onto your site through a `<video>` tag. The youtube iframe api is designed **only** for having videos that function exactly like they do on the youtube website, which includes the things you don't want.